# brightness of google map V2 is very low

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2, android-alertdialog

I am displaying a bigger version of google map once user click on the small fragment which display map. I am displaying bigger version of map starting map activity in dialog mode. every thing is working fine but the only problem is displayed map is very dull not bright how i can keep it bright. any help will be appriciated.

[image]

Comment: I am guessing you are using a DialogFragment? There are some issues with using GoogleMaps in Dialogs. There are some workarounds using style parameters. See link that might be helpful: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the Theme you are using for your activity. user587650's answer is correct. You can find the solution inside that page. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4902

By simply adding these items inside my themes.xml file I could solve the problem.

[image]

Hope it helps!